# Trying to set value for Progress Circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

Is there a way I can hard code a number into the code instead of having "Goals completed: " and the progress bar still complete based on percentage? I do not want the users to see "Goals Completed" or have a input bar where they enter a number. I want to do all of that behind the scenes.

What I am really trying to do is get rid of the whole "Goals Completed: (input box)" prompt. So that I, for example, can just hard code: goals = 69 and then the progress circle reacts and shows 60% in the middle and 69 of 115 goals completed AND the green circle on the outside matches that. I do not want the user to be able to enter anywhere how many goals were completed or see a input prompt. I want to only be able to modify the number of goals completed behind the scenes in the JS code.

Here is my current code:

```js
document.querySelector('.goals').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var goals = parseInt(this.value);
  var circle = document.querySelector('circle');
  var percentdiv = document.querySelector('.percent');
  var completed = document.querySelector('.completed');
  completed.innerHTML = goals;
  var totaldiv = document.querySelector('.total');
  var total = totaldiv.innerHTML;
  var pc = goals * 100 / total;
  var r = circle.getAttribute('r').replace('%', '') * percentdiv.clientWidth / 100; //actual radius of the circle
  var c = Math.PI * (r * 2); //circumference is 2*pi*r

  if (isNaN(goals)) {
    pc = 100;
  } else if (pc < 0) {
    pc = 0;
  } else if (pc > 100) {
    pc = 100;
  }
  document.querySelector('.number h2').innerHTML = Math.floor(pc) + '<span>%</span>';

  var length = pc * c / 100;

  circle.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + (c - length);
  circle.style.strokeWidth = (length > 0) ? '5%' : 0;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .card:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.percent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  rbox-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #000;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#444 0%, #222 70%, transparent 70%, transparent 100%);
  rbackground: #222;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.percent .number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.percent .number h2 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.percent .number h2 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #777;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 span {
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

svg circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #00ff43;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="percent">
        <svg>
                      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="47.5%"></circle>
                    </svg>
        <div class="number">
          <h2>0<span>%</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="text"><span class="completed">0</span> of <span class="total">115</span> Goals Completed</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Goals completed: <input class="goals" type='number' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having your logic for updating the circle stored in the event handler for the input, have it as a separate function which you can then call with any number, e.g. `setGoals(50)` would update the circle to say `50 of 115 goals completed` and `43%`.

You can then *optionally* include the input box to change the displayed value in the circle, or just call `setGoals(<some number here>)` anywhere in your code.

This gives you the code snippet:

```js
function setGoals(goals) {
  const circle = document.querySelector('circle');
  const percentdiv = document.querySelector('.percent');
  const completed = document.querySelector('.completed');
  completed.innerHTML = goals;
  const totaldiv = document.querySelector('.total');
  const total = totaldiv.innerHTML;
  let pc = goals * 100 / total;
  const r = circle.getAttribute('r').replace('%', '') * percentdiv.clientWidth / 100; //actual radius of the circle
  const c = Math.PI * (r * 2); //circumference is 2*pi*r

  if (isNaN(goals)) {
    pc = 100;
  } else if (pc < 0) {
    pc = 0;
  } else if (pc > 100) {
    pc = 100;
  }
  document.querySelector('.number h2').innerHTML = Math.floor(pc) + '<span>%</span>';

  const length = pc * c / 100;

  circle.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + (c - length);
  circle.style.strokeWidth = (length > 0) ? '5%' : 0;
}

// For testing purposes, set up the input box to edit the number of displayed goals
document.querySelector('.goals').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const goals = parseInt(e.target.value);
  setGoals(goals);
});

// On page load, manually set the goals to 50 for demonstration purposes
setGoals(50);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .card:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.percent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  rbox-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #000;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#444 0%, #222 70%, transparent 70%, transparent 100%);
  rbackground: #222;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.percent .number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.percent .number h2 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.percent .number h2 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #777;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 span {
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

svg circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #00ff43;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="percent">
        <svg>
                      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="47.5%"></circle>
                    </svg>
        <div class="number">
          <h2>0<span>%</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="text"><span class="completed">0</span> of <span class="total">115</span> Goals Completed</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Goals completed: <input class="goals" type='number' />
```

...It's a little difficult to test here on Stack Overflow, but if you call `setGoals(50)` (or another number) then it'll update the displayed goals in the circle. I added the line `setGoals(50)` to the above code snippet as an example to show 50 goals on page load.

Comment: Thank you for the help Robbie, I guess what I am really trying to do is get rid of the whole "Goals Completed: (input box)" prompt. So that I, for example, can just hard code: goals = 69 and then the progress circle reacts and shows 60% in the middle and 69 of 115 goals completed. I do not want the user to be able to enter anywhere how many goals were completed or see a input prompt. I want to only be able to modify the number of goals completed behind the scenes in the JS code.

Comment: Apologies @OdinsCode, looks like I misunderstood! I've updated the answer now, hopefully this better matches what you need.

Comment: Amazing thank you @Robbie starring at code for so long sometimes you forget you can just create a function to encapsulate it!